# PHP - Loop number of selected check boxes on form submit

Tags: php, forms

I have an issue where I need to loop the number of check boxes on a form submit. Foreach check box that is looped I need to then insert data into the database.
How Would I go about looping over the amount of check boxes that have being passed via form submit?

My code is as follows:

**Form:**

```
<form action="createChallenge.php" method="post" name="chalCreate">
    Challenge Name:<input type="text" name="chalName" />
    <br />
    Challenge Target:<input type="text"  name="chalTarget"/>
    <br />
    End Date:<input type="text" name="chalDate">
    <br />
    <!-- Needs a jquery datepicker -->
    Select Friends: <br />
    <?php
       $selFriend = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Friends WHERE UserID = '$userID' AND Friend = 'y' ORDER BY FriendName ASC");
       $selFriend->execute();
       foreach($selFriend as $row){
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="<?php echo $row['FriendID'] ?>"><?php echo $row['FriendName'] ?><br>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

<br />
<button type="submit">Create Challenge</button>
</form>
```

**PHP to handle the form:**

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['test']))
        {
            $i = 0;
            foreach($_POST['test'] as $checked)
            {
                echo $friend = $checked;
                $i++;
            }


            echo $name = $_POST['chalName'];
            echo $target = $_POST['chalTarget'];
            echo $date = $_POST['chalDate'];
            echo $friend = $_POST['test'];
            echo $setby = $_COOKIE['userID'];

            $create = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Challenge ( chalSetBy, chalName, chalTarget, chalDate ) VALUES ('$setby', '$name', '$target', '$date') ");
            $create->execute();

            if($create)
            {
                echo "Challenge made successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "There was a problem";
            }
        }
      ?>
```

I thought doing the following would echo out data, but it didn't, it only selected the last check box:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($_POST['test'] as $checked)
{
    echo $friend = $checked;
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array of your checkbox in HTML page like as below,

```
<form name="frm" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="test[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="test[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="test[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="test[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="test[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="6" name="test[]">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php 
foreach($_POST['test'] as $key=>$value)
{
echo $value."<br>";

}
```

Comment: Side note: Using `echo $value . "\n";` or `echo $value . " ";` will put a space between all entries, otherwise it will end up as being, for example: `123456` instead of (probably intended) `1 2 3 4 5 6` and for line breaks `echo $value . "<br>";` (Just a thought)